# WebParts keep loading untill I scroll down the page or perform a zoom

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, spfx-extensions

environment:SharePoint online;Sharepoint Framework;
Programming languages:TypeScript

During page loading, sharepoint custom web part keeps on loading
[image]

Nothing does change untill I scroll down the page or perform a zoom,once a do, all works just fluently.

Comment: Hi, could u please check ur browser console as if it is giving any error.

Comment: init.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
    at q (https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7407.1203/init.js:1:171357)
    at https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7407.1203/init.js:1:172234
    at arguments.(anonymous function) (https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/16.0.7407.1203/init.js:1:99714)

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Reset IE settings.
2. Switch to other browsers.
3. Check if the logic is right in the custom web part.

There is a similar post:

https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/22517

Comment: solution didn't work.

Comment: however ,when open the console and reload the page all works well

Comment: It is very happy that the issue is resolved.